# WiX ServiceInstall Service Dependency

Tags: wix, serviceinstall

How do I set a dependency for a service in the WiX ServiceInstall attribute to depend on, for example, LmHosts

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<ServiceInstall Id="ServiceNameId" Type="ownProcess" Name="ServiceName"
                DisplayName="Service Display Name"
                Description="Service Description" Start="auto" Account="LOCALSYSTEM"
                ErrorControl="normal">
      <ServiceDependency Id="LmHosts" />
</ServiceInstall>
```